# Как проверить авторизацию/вход в аккаунт на PHP с помощью сессий?

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

пишу сайт для онлайн обучения на PHP + RedBean и столкнулся с такой проблемой. На странице index.php, обычный пользователь, который не зарегистрировался либо не вошёл в аккаунт должен видеть две кнопки Войти/Регистрация. А пользователям которые уже вошли в аккаунт должны видеть кнопку настройки профиля. Вопрос: Как мне проверить вошёл ли пользователь в аккаунт? Попробовал вот этот способ.
Когда пользователь авторизовался(***Login.php***):

```
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
```

После в ***index.php***:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
  //показать кнопку настройки профиля
}
else {
  //показать кнопки вход/регистрация
}
```

Но почему-то в любом случае отображается кнопки войти/регистрация

Comment: В условии оставьте только `$_SESSION['loggedin'] == true`, а так же воспользуйтесь строгим оператором `===` вместо `==`

Comment: `Warning: Undefined array key "loggedin" `

Comment: Ошибка сообщает что такой записи в сессии не найдено, т.е. она не добавлена туда. Воспользуйтесь var_dump($_SESSION), что бы понять что находится в сессии.
Возможно вы стартуете сессию где-то не там...

Comment: И правда такой записи нет. Вроде сессию стартую где надо но от ошибки не избавился)

Comment: а вы session_start() делаете в каждом файле .php?

Comment: в меню devtools (F12) идите в Application->Cookies->ВАШ_ХОСТ проверьте есть ли там ваши значения

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем как работать с сессиями необходимо создать, либо возобновить сессию с помощью `session_start();`

Comment: Уже имеется такое)